# How to solve 'Requirements check failed' error when installing Apache Cordova on Android using JDK 11 and SDK 13?

Tags: java, android, cordova, sdk

i can't solve this problem.
i was trying to do a small project in apache cordova but i am totally new to mobile development.
I followed the guide they propose on the apache site for the first simple project but it didn't work.
I am currently using cordova 11 with jdk 11 and android sdk 13 but something is not working.
Can someone help me?

below find the output of the `cordova requirements` command

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with ENOENT: avdmanager list target
spawn avdmanager ENOENT
Gradle: installed ###/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/8.1.1/bin/gradle
Some of requirements check failed
```

first I installed the latest version of android studio, then I reinstalled the necessary sdk and also the emulator with google pixel that I had previously created.
i downloaded different versions of openjdk and tried to fix the problem but it doesn't work

I use Ubuntu 20.04